# React and Firebase Deploy: Giving blank page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my app to firebase. It is a one page application. I had success when deploying previously, in the beggining of the development to see if Redux and Router were working(they were). But now in my final stage when I deploy I get and empty page I can't figure out why. I know it has something to do with it was suppose to be a javascript file and when it sees the < it crashes, but don't know why...

It gives me the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

When doing `firebase init` I chose

```
 What do you want to use as your public directory? build 
 ? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes 
 ? File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
```

My `firebase.json`looks like this

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
    ]
  }
}
```

[My package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlLdi.png)

Comment: Hi Zhast, i am also facing similar issue , can you write how its resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. To get rid of the syntax error. I have to put semi-colons after every import in every file... I haven't figured out the proper way to fix the manifest error yet though.